# List all tracked and untracked files considering the standard Git exclusion

Tags: bash, git

Is there a way to list all *tracked* and *untracked* files considering the standard Git exclusion like (.git/info/exclude, .gitignore)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use bash grouping commands with *git ls-files*

```
{ git ls-files --exclude-standard --other; git ls-files; }
```

Comment: nice! did not know about `ls-files`

Comment: Please note Bash demands a trailing semicolon inside the curly braces: `{ git ls-files --exclude-standard --other; git ls-files; }`